# Create an overlay for Titanium Mobile TableView

Tags: mobile, datepicker, overlay, titanium, tableview

I'm trying to create a DatePicker that slides in over a TableView in order to edit a date-field. The problem is that the DatePicker appears behind the TableView - you can see a part of it because the TableView is transparent.

[image]

I tried giving one a higher zIndex value than the other, both ways, but that didn't help. The datepicker is a picker control in a view, which I slide up with an animation.

How does one overlay a TableView with a different view?

Edit: the table is quite complicated because of the various types of data in it, so copy&paste would be overkill. But here's the relevant part:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({zIndex: 1});

// some table sections are added here

// create picker layer
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({zIndex: 2});
var picker_view = Titanium.UI.createView({
  height: 251,
  bottom: -251,
  zIndex: 3,
  visible: false
  });

var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
  type: Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
  selectionIndicator: true
  });
picker_view.add(picker);

row.addEventListener('click', function()
  {
  picker_view.visible = true;
  var slide_in = Titanium.UI.createAnimation({bottom:0});
  picker_view.animate(slide_in);
  });

row.add(picker_view);

some_section.add(row);
win.add(table);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, updated the question with some code.

Comment: try to add the picker in your window, not in table

Comment: Of course you're right, when I add it to the window it works. Obvious if you think about it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to Add the picker in the window not in table.

Answer (score 2):

dont add the view to the row, add it to the window.

dont set visibility on the view, it is irrelevant since you are sliding it up and down.

also you really are confusing things with the zIndexes, they are not really needed in this use case.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Like Muhammad also suggested, it was adding it to the window that did the trick. I had the visibility flag because when adding it to the row, you would of course see the "hidden" picker if you pull the table up a bit. Adding it to the window voids that idea. The zIndexes are actually required though, if I don't set the table to 1 and the pickerview to 2, it will open behind the table. I guess that has to do with the order of adding them to the window though. In my case it makes more sense to use zIndex though. Thanks!